# Listen for EDMX conversion?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

When re-targeting a project from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5 in VS2012 any EDMX in the project is automatically converted to EF 5, i.e., the namespaces are updated to match the target framework.

Is there a way, maybe via an extension to the EDM Tools, to "listen" for this conversion?  We use custom annotations in the EDMX, and when the upgrade is performed also need to convert/update our annotations.

We currently implement IModelTransformExtension to perform custom logic when the model is loaded and saved, and in theory we can use the OnAfterModelLoaded to do the conversion of the annotations too, but since the conversion is needed one time only, and always specifically when the .NET framework is retargeted, it would be great if there's another option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can do this in a more straightforward way by adding a code generation item (t4 template) to your edmx and edit it to include the custom annotations.

Comment: Thanks.  We display the annotations from the EDMX in the EDM Properties window, and then use them in our T4 code generation.  Since we want the annotated values to be editable via the Properties window, I'm not sure how your suggestion would work for us.

Comment: Hi,
I was wondering whether you found a solution to this, as I have a similar issue where I'd like to be able to control the EF Designer.
Thanks